# How to use CASE WHEN THEN SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to set a return result based on the Height of a product. If the product is greater than 86 I want to return Transom along with the result set if it is less than I what to return No Transom.

I'm attempting to use the CASE WHEN below to evaluate the result, but my implementation is incorrect.

```
    SELECT c.ID, 
        (p.Number +'|'+ pr.[Profile] +'|'+ SUBSTRING(CAST((p.Width - (pr.Siteline * 2))AS VARCHAR(9)),0,3)  
        + 'x84' +'|Pivot:'+e.PivotType+'|Hinge:'+e.Hinged +'|Swing:'+e.Swing) as [Name],
        ('Header:'+ CAST(pr.Siteline as VARCHAR(7))+'|Jamb:'+ CAST(pr.Siteline as VARCHAR(7)))as[Sitelines],

       CASE p.Height 
            WHEN > 86 THEN 'Transom'
            ELSE 'No Transom'

FROM            Generic.Part           p WITH(NOLOCK)                          JOIN
                Generic.Profiles      pr WITH(NOLOCK) ON p.ProfileID = pr.ID   JOIN
                Generic.ComponentPart cp WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.PartID   = p.ID    JOIN
                Generic.Component      c WITH(NOLOCK) ON cp.ComponentID = c.ID JOIN
                Generic.ComponentType ct WITH(NOLOCK) ON ct.ID = c.ComponentTypeID JOIN
                Generic.FramingSystem fs WITH(NOLOCK) ON fs.ID = c.FrameSystemID   JOIN
                Generic.Entrance       e WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.ID = e.DoorFrameID
                WHERE fs.UserID = 'DA91DC34-FA29-4ABD-BCC0-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't say what the actual error is, but try:

```
CASE
    WHEN p.Height > 86 THEN 'Transom'
    ELSE 'No Transom'
END AS [ColumnName]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing the `END`:

```
   CASE p.Height 
        WHEN > 86 THEN 'Transom'
        ELSE 'No Transom'
   END
```